# How to handle NAs in along coasts in ISRIC soil raster data for SDM of a coastal species?

Tags: raster, na, terra, biomod2

I'm working with a dataset of tree species which are mostly found along coastal areas in Southeast Asia in order to produce a species distribution model to look for novel surveying sites in New Guinea. After filtering the data to remove spatial/temporal/geographic biases, I have a rather small dataset of 70 occurences, and when I run the data in biomod2 (or ecospat) in R, 45/70 of my occurences are removed due to NA in my ISRIC soil data layers (phh2o, N, silt).

For a visual, you can see in qgis my occurence points which occur on land in my elevation layer (light green), but appear to be in the ocean in my soil layer (gray). [occurence points on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gezL.png)[more occurence points on map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNYEu.png).

Is there any methodology for predicting/filling these NA areas on my raster data? How have other people handled working with soil data in coastal areas?

I have already made sure my data is aligned, cropped, and projected properly. I have also thought to just reduce my dataset to only using the occurence points in presence areas, by running an ensemble of small models (Breiner 2015, 2018). But, I am still worried how representative the model will be if I have to exclude many occurence points in coastal areas.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be much appreciated!

```
`# 2013 WDC Soils 

#load soils --------
filelist_temp <- list.files(path = "map/", full.names = TRUE)
soil30 <- rast(filelist_temp)

res(soil30)
ext(soil30)

cec1k <- rast("C:/intsia/cec_0-5cm_mean_1000.tif")

#reproject via bilinear interpolation 
cec <- project(cec1k, soil30) 
res(cec)
ext(cec)

#stack soils 
soil <- c(cec, soil30)

#crop to sea extent
soil_crp <- crop(soil, e.bij)


#aggregate
soil5 <- aggregate(soil_crp, fact=5, fun = "mean", progress="text")

rm(soil, cec, cec1k, soil30, soil_crp)

#check crs
crs(soil5[[1]]) == crs(wind5[[1]]) #true
#check ext
ext(soil5[[1]]) == ext(wind5[[1]]) #true`
```

Comment: welcome to SO! You could edit and improve your question by making it more focused (do not distract with background research objectives), and, most importantly, making your example *minimal, self-contained and reproducible".  That is, use data created by code or that ship with R (e.g. the elevation data that you see in the example of `?rast`. And add a point just outside the area with values as an example.